# VPN with "Network Bridge" help needed

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, wired-networking

So, essentially my setup has two computers (One Arch Linux, one Windows 10) connected via Ethernet, then bridging with WiFi on the "Main PC" (Windows). The Linux PC does not have any sort of way to connect to the internet other than this -- So here's the question:

How can I, with the Windows system, run a VPN (To be specific, Proton VPN) to connect to the VPN for both PCs? So that my secondary PC (The Linux one) as well as my primary PC will both be protected with said VPN?

I've attempted to Bridge the Network Tunnel created by the VPN when active...but I highly doubt that even in the best-case environments, that that would work. I've been researching this, but the problem being that the term "VPN Bridge" is a separate term entirely..

I do not wish to connect to my VPN through the router. Also, I can connect to the VPN on the Linux PC ofc with no problems -- but I wish for both internet connections to be more secure.

Does anybody have a possible solution, by chance? Sorry if I misused any terminology here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot bridge a wireless network adapter to other adapters (wired or wireless) since, for both technical and security reasons, only the device performing the wireless connection and negotiation can be connected to the wireless network on the link-layer.

Instead, you can have your Windows 10 computer act as a router/NAT and allow the wired computer (your Linux box in this case). The only downside is that your Linux box will not have an external IP address and therefore will not be able to receive incoming connections.

If that's OK with you try following this short guide -

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/internet-connection-sharing-in-windows-10/f6dcac4b-5203-4c98-8cf2-dcac86d98fb9

(You may need to change the option in step 5 to whatever the wired network adapter is).

Comment: It wouldn't receive incoming connections, as in, it wouldn't receive any data from outside the home network? So, for example, I wouldn't be able to go to google? Or do you mean something else with that? Apologies, I'm still learning about all this.

Comment: No, it just means you wouldn't be able to initialize connections from the Internet (e.g., you won't be able to SSH into the box from outside, P2P software like BitTorrent will have connection issues etc.). No effect on connecting from your box to the Internet.

Comment: Understood -- many thanks.