# Connect to VPN server on computer A from computer C with blocked connection

Tags: networking, vpn

I wasn't sure what exactly to title this post, but here is my issue:
I want to connect to the VPN server on computer A from computer C, but the connection is disallowed in the configuration I currently have them in. The solution to this problem is to connect from `A->B->C`

How would I go about setting up computer B in a way that allows it to forward all traffic it receives from computer C to computer A, thus allowing the VPN connection? Does this involve a second VPN?

Comment: Does this involve a second VPN?   .........  As far as I know, yes.

Comment: Either a second VPN, a multi-hop SSH, or SSH from A → B then VPN from B → C

Comment: It depends -- are the PC's in the same LAN or not? See https://superuser.com/questions/1756731/vpn-with-network-bridge-help-needed, for example.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik They are not in the same LAN.